# How can a third party track/fetch a web project's API network calls through code?

Tags: javascript, sentry

I want to know how can third-party apps access API network calls. Like the API's request headers, response headers, payload, etc.
Example - Sentry has a feature "Relay" which can track user movements and even records API calls.

Shouldn't there be some browser restriction to such cases, as the sensitive data will also be forwarded?

Answer (score 1):

With Relay the client-side code making the requests is changed so it makes the requests to the Relay server instead.

Since it is receiving the request, it has full access to it.